# How do I remove a container if child element contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site that aggregates video clips from YouTube. But sometimes a clip shows up as private. How can I set `display:none;` via jQuery on the whole `div` if the class `a.colorbox.cboxElement` contains the string "*Private video*"?

I have done something like this on single `div`s before that adda an extra class that I use to remove the div. I'm unsure what do to when it's nested:

```
$( "#div:contains('text')" ).addClass( "newclass" );
```

The HTML:

```
<li class="feed-item">
    <div class="thumbnail-excerpt wprss-feed-thumbnail sgvtagged">
        <div class="SGVthumb SGVthumb-0" data-title="SKateFlix" data-desc="The Amazing SkateFlix" data-type="yt" style="width:280px;height:210px;float:left;padding-right:px" data-media="SGVvideo" data-thumb="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2A7vCq8BmQQ" data-yid="2A7vCq8BmQQ" data-image="0" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2A7vCq8BmQQ?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0"><img height="210" width="280" src="http://skateflix.se/wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/www-gstatic-com/3140846889.png"><img class="mpover" src="http://skateflix.se/wp-content/plugins/sgvideo/img/ytp.png" style="left:40px;top:40px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="source-date"><span class="feed-source">VANS </span></div>
    <a class="datum">onsdag, maj 6</a>
    <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2A7vCq8BmQQ">Private video</a>
    <div class="colorboxexcerpt" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2A7vCq8BmQQ">...</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) with [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$( ".feed-item:has(a.cboxElement:contains('Private video'))" ).hide();
```

This example has one Private and one Public video:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7vramkem/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the `li` ancestor of the anchor element

```
$( "a.cboxElement:contains('text')" ).closest('.feed-item').hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9eyj2dop/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.feed-item').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.cboxElement').text() === "Private Video"){
            $(this).addClass( "newclass" );
        }
    });
```

Unrelated to when or how you want to do the check, this if() should do the job

Comment: This is actually wrong as you are testing all anchors (not just the one in the feed-item). You need to scope the inner search.

Comment: Better, but a `filter()` call would be more efficient than `each` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, ah cool. I'm of course still a learner, thanks =) Xeptor, I had a  type inside the if() where i missed a ".", replace with this: $(this).addClass( "newclass" );